# balloon.css hide tooltip on mobile

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to hide one CSS file called `balloon.css` on mobile devices. I'm using this `balloon.css`: [balloon.css](https://kazzkiq.github.io/balloon.css/)

My code:

```
    @media only screen
   and (min-device-width : 320px)
   and (max-device-width : 480px){[data-balloon] { visibility: hidden; }}
```

Thanks guys for helping!

Comment: Do you want to hide the entire css file

Comment: Yes, i dont want to use balloon.css on mobiles

Answer (score 4):

Since `balloon.css` uses pseudo classes for hover effect you need to hide those in your media queries.

```
@media only screen
   and (min-device-width : 320px)
   and (max-device-width : 480px){
 [data-balloon]:after,
 [data-balloon]:before { display: none; }
}
```

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide a certain script of css on mobile use resolutions

```
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
.data-balloon {
display: none
}
```

use display none, for no display.